# Configure ipython to automatically use certain settings like doctest_mode on

Tags: ipython

I know ipython has a very extensive configuration system.  I've looked all over in the generated ipython_config.py file for a way to configure certain settings.  I would like to always start ipython with %doctest_mode on.

Is there an easy way to do this?  I've tried adding this command in the c.TerminalIpythonApp.code_to_run configuration option.  However, this causes ipython to start up, run the command and exit instead of being interactive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `code_to_run`, find these lines in your config file:

```
# lines of code to run at IPython startup.
# c.InteractiveShellApp.exec_lines = []
```

If you put commands in there, they'll be executed, and you can use IPython interactively.

Comment: Thanks! I just put 'doctest_mode on' in the exec_lines list and everything works just like I would expect.

Comment: i had to make mine
c.InteractiveShellApp.exec_lines = ['%doctest_mode on']